# Is there a way to allow others to use my SpotiPy application?

Tags: python, authentication, access-token, spotipy

To preface, I am pretty new to Python, using APIs, authentication, and access tokens, so excuse me if I am misinformed.

I have created a Spotipy application that imports my personal listening data into a Google Sheet. My goal with this project is to allow my friends to use it, collect their data (with permission of course), and create a machine learning model from it (not sure what yet). Of course, they will be allowed to see their own listening data as well. I essentially want to create my own version of Receiptify.

The problem I am facing right now is that I am the only person who can use the application since I have authorized myself using my own client id, as well as generated my own access token. I was wondering if I could have some guidance as to how I could allow others to use my application without having to manually provide their own client id.

Here is an example I found: receiptify.herokuapp.com/

tldr - I want to replicate receiptify but I do not know how to allow others to use my application without having them manually provide a client id.

I am happy to answer any further questions or provide some implementation. Thanks to those willing to help!